# wait until response received in Angular2 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-services

Actually I need to wait until response received from webapi call from typescript. Code is given below:

```
if (this.parcelId) {
            if (this.getAssetLocationMappedParcels(this.parcelId)) {
                this.showConfirmModal = true;
                this.modalContent = this.translation.translate('property-tax/mapped-asset-location-warning-message',
                    { 'parcelName': this.currentEntity.name });
            } else {
                this.updateParcel();
            }
        }

private getAssetLocationMappedParcels(parcelId: number): boolean {
        let hasMappedRecord: boolean = false;
        this.counter++;
        this.mappedAssetLocationSub = this.apiService.fetchAll(`assetlocationtaxlocationtaxparcel/${parcelId}/parcel`)
            .finally(
            () => this.counter--
            )
            .subscribe(options => {
                hasMappedRecord = (options.count > 0);
            },
            err => {
                this.handleError(err || err.message);
            }
            );
        return hasMappedRecord;
    }
```

So my problem is that the condition **if(getAssetLocationMappedParcels(id))** gets passed and execute in the else condition after that, that method return value as true/false;
For this I need to wait until that method returns a response.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever you write inside subscribe will only work after you get the response

Comment: This is an option to do but is there any other options except subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

It's an async world, so you must work with this "constraint".

I don't think there is another solution than to do a subscribe:

```
this.getAssetLocationMappedParcels(this.parcelId)
    .subscribe(isLoaded => {
       if (isLoaded) {
         this.showConfirmModal = true;
         this.modalContent = this.translation
             .translate(
                 'property-tax/mapped-asset-location-warning-message', 
                 {'parcelName': this.currentEntity.name}
             );
       } else 
         this.updateParcel();
      })
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion! :) but With this approach, I have done already.